# Why can't i use react.createContext()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-context

Hi so i have been trying to implement react context api into my project, After follow the steps in the guide: https://developerhandbook.com/react/build-a-complete-property-listings-page-with-react/

I ended up getting an error when i tried to display some of the information.

This is the error i got in my console log:

```
OrderListProvider.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__.createContext is not a function
    at Object../src/context/OrderListProvider.js (OrderListProvider.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:88)
    at Object../src/components/Home.js (FetchData.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:88)
    at Object../src/App.js (fetch.js:461)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:88)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.css?f255:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:88)
    at Object.0 (registerServiceWorker.js:108)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:678)
    at bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:724
    at bootstrap 39db4eed0e38b5656c68:724
```

I tried updating my react since the guide mentioned i need 16.3 at least, and i only had 16.0.0.

However after updating react to the newest version it still says the same thing. I can’t seem to find any information about it in the release notes on github.

This is my createContext function:

```
const OrderListContext = React.createContext(DefaultState);
```

And this is where i consume it:

```
<OrderListProvider>
                <OrderListConsumer>
                    {function (value) {
                        const { orderList } = value
                        return (
                            <ul>
                                {orderList.map(listing => (
                                    <li>{listing.varetitle}</li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        )
                    }}
                </OrderListConsumer>
            </OrderListProvider>
```

edit: This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "React_Demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

edit2: I have recreated my code in stackblitz without data from a fetch funktion: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssqc4t It doesn't seem to show the error so i don't understand why my code doesn't work in visual studio 2017

edit3: I have also tried to verify and clear my npm cache, but it still shows the same error.

edit4: Node.js have also been updates to the newest version. Still the same error.

Comment: did you `import React from 'react'`? did you restart webpack dev server after installation of new version?

Comment: ```const OrderListContext = React.createContext(DefaultState)``` and yes i included ``` import * as React from 'react ```

Comment: Is there a special way to restart the webpack dev server? i just launced iis express from Visual studio.

Comment: stop it and start it again... or restart visual studio ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to get it to work, by deleting my entire node module folder and installing it again with

`npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade the version of `react` & `react-dom` to **v16.4** or above.

```
npm update react react-dom
```

If you are using yarn, you can run

```
yarn upgrade react react-dom
```

**Working demo 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-context-api-456158**

Comment: Sorry i should have included the package.json, but i have updated it to 16.10.2 and it still shows the same error

Comment: I have attached the link where you can find the working demo. Can you please compare it and try to identify the issue?

Comment: From what i can see the only diffrence is that i have included a default state. I tried removing it, but it still gave the same error

Comment: Is it possible for you to replicate same issue on stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ssqc4t I made it almost exactly like mine, just without fetching the data. and i added it to the default state. the problem doesn't show tho so i'm not sure whats happening

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fetch function then? edit: nope still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

export Context const and it will work as below:

```
export const OrderListContext = React.createContext(DefaultState);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).